# autocomplete AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, class, serialization, autocomplete, geojson

How to solve this problem?

```
in validate_commune
    fields=('name',)),
/my_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 94, in serialize
    concrete_model = obj._meta.concrete_model
AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

#models.py

```
   class Wilaya(models.Model):
        id = models.BigIntegerField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=75)``
        geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
        matricule=models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,null=False)    
        def __str__(self):
           return self.name

    
    class Commune(models.Model):
        id = models.BigIntegerField()
        name = models.CharField(max_length=75)
        geom = models.MultiPolygonField(srid=4326)
        wilaya=models.ForeignKey(Wilaya,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,null=True)
        def __str__(self):
           return self.name
```

#views.py

```
    def validate_commune(request):
        commune=request.GET.get('id_commune',None)  
        data={
            serialize('geojson',Commune.objects.get(id=int(commune)).geom, 
            geometry_field='geom',
            fields=('name',)),
        }
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

problem solved with add name field in :

```
#forms.py
labels={
'name':_("Name :"),
...
}
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
   self.helper = FormHelper()
   self.helper.layout = Layout(
      Row(
          Column('name', css_class='form-group col-md-2 mb-0'),
          ...
          css_class='form-row'
          ),
  Submit('submit', 'Register')
  )
```